# How to solve an errorconnected with Pick of date in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

So I'm trying to change the date in Datepicker and use the changed value after in my application. And I can't figure out what's going on. I'm changing the date in onChange event of Datepicker and save that date in onChangePicker(). But in onChangePicker() when I log the saved value in Console I see the previous value not current. Even sleep function is not helping at all.  What is wrong? How can I access the current value?

My code is

```
const Datagrid = () => {
    const [Info, setInfo] = useState(new Date())
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  async function onChangePicker(date_new) {
    setInfo(date_new)
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log(Info)
  }
                  return (
                <div className="App">
                   <DatePicker dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" selected={Info} 
                      onChange={(date_new) => {
                      onChangePicker(date_new)
                   }} />

                </div>
              );
}
```

Comment: the variable `Info` doesn't get immeditaely changed when you do `setInfo` -- it changes in the NEXT render cycle. THIS render cycle, it's still the old value.

Comment: try doing a console.log before `return (`, you'll see the updated value then.

Comment: So, for  change data and print it in one render i shold not use hooks at all?

Comment: You're using hooks perfectly correct, except you're not exactly understanding what's going on with them, which is why you're expecting your 'console.log' to log something different from what it actually logs. The way you're changing it is just fine.